# VBA MACRO that copies a specific data from all excel file and paste in the current excel sheet2 named"Export"

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to macro/vba... I am trying to create a macro the loops in a specified folder and copies data from sheet1 named "View Shipments" and paste it in the current workbook in sheet2 named "Export". However, my code below is not working as I am getting error in line below first where I have specifed the folder path.

Secondly, I am not understanding how to code for the range that is to be copied. All excel file in the folder named "DailyDownl" has similar data so I want to copy the range from Cell "A2" till all data i.e. trying to copy the data without header row column in each excel file. FOr that when I gave "A2: AAA2" is copied only that row but not the entire data from that sheet neither from other sheets.
I will highlight everything in below screenshots one after another.

All I want the macro to do is... The macro should loop within a folder named "DailyDownl" and copy data present in sheet1 which is named as "View Shipments" and copy entire data without the header row or top row i.e. and paste all the data in current workbook sheet2 named as export.

Comment: `If strPath <> "C:\Path\DailyDownL\" Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted function:

```
Sub CopyData(shSource As Worksheet, shTarget As Worksheet)
   Dim lastTRow As Long
    
    lastTRow = shTarget.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    shSource.Range(shSource.Range("A2"), shSource.cells(shSource.UsedRange.rows.count , shSource.Columns.count)).Copy
    shTarget.cells(lastTRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks the part for copy has worked but still there is a problem in folder identification. Please see my edits above I have pasted the complete code with the one what you edited. Please assist in the folder identification condition part, please

Comment: @Jay Sameer: What "my edits above" are you talking about? If you try modifying my answer by editing it this will all the time be rejected. So, should I understand that your function retrieving the folder path does not work as you need?

Comment: I did not edit thing in your answer I have pasted you edit in the main code @FaneDuru Your answer in part is correct and working but the still the problem persist that with the codes for the folder path...

Comment: Now the problem is in this part " ' Make sure a folder was picked.
    If Not strPath = "C:\FolderPath\DailyDownL\" Then

        ' Get all the files from the folder
        strfile = Dir$(strPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)

So in my question above this part is still pending. I mean I want the macro to locate the folder and do the next task

Comment: @Jay Sameer: I do not see any editing in your answer code... What did you change? The function I adapted is exactly like before. But, besides that, does your code accept all paths **except** "C:\FolderPath\DailyDownL\"? Dis is what you wont doing? Then, do you need iterating between all .xls files or between all Excel files (xls, xlsx, xlsm, xlsb)?

Comment: Please see the question I have changed the codes there now...

Comment: Now it is not locating the folder by itself and not looping further its stops

Comment: @Jay Sameer: I have to remind that you did not answer my above questions.

Comment: This is resolved @FaneDuru I have removed the If Condition and gave the folder path at first
' get the folder path that has the files
    Set shTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export")
    strPath = "C:\FolderPath\DailyDownL\"

Comment: Now this is working fine

Comment: @Jay Sameer: OK. Glad I could help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223169/discussion-between-jay-sameer-and-faneduru).